# copy particular div from Flipkart.com web scraping using Curl and Php

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I want to copy particular div contain data from flipkart product web page and display it.

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="specTable">
///// contains  /////
</table>
```

its table value are variable in some web page have 10 tables in same class and some page have more, how i can get all table value from this ?

Also wants to get specific specsValue, is it possible to get it also ?

```
<td class="specsKey">Brand</td><td class="specsValue">Apple</td>
```

Web page address: http://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-6/p/itme8ra5z7yx5c9j?pid=MOBEYHZ2JHVFHFBG

Sample code

```
$url = "http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/apple-iphone-6/p/itme8ra5z7yx5c9j?pid=MOBEYHZ2JHVFHFBG";

$response = getPriceFromFlipkart($url);

echo json_encode($response);

/* Returns the response in JSON format */

function getPriceFromFlipkart($url) {

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.10; labnol;) ctrlq.org");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<meta itemprop="price" content="([^"]*)"/';
preg_match($regex, $html, $price);

$regex = '/<h1[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/h1>/';
preg_match($regex, $html, $title);

$regex = '/data-src="([^"]*)"/i';
preg_match($regex, $html, $image);

if ($price && $title && $image) {

    $response = array("price" => $price[1], "title" => $title[1], "image" => $image[1]);

} else {

    $response = array("status" => "404", "error" => "We could not find the product details on Flipkart $url");

}

return $response;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flipkart now change its interface and you can fetch the product price and all by using [Flipkart API](https://affiliate.flipkart.com/api-docs/affiliate_index.html).
Currently I'm also using their API.

But I also want to fetch the product details using below curl command, if anyone is doing the same without any problem please share what else i have to add here to fetch the product webpage content, while debugging this by using getinfo() it will return `301 Moved Permanently`with `Status Code 0`

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,<flipkart_url>);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,100);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.flipkart.com/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');

$str = curl_exec($curl_handle);         
$html = new simple_html_dom();          
$html->load($str);
```